# Mi JScrollPane hace que mi JTable no se muestre (Java)

Tags: java, jtable

Estoy haciendo un programa en Java en el que, entre otras cosas, tengo que incluir una tabla en un `JFrame` junto con otros componentes que ya tengo en un `JPanel`.

Mi programa es un juego de piedra-papel-tijera que incluye registros de usuarios por interfaz gráfica y retos. Cuando un usuario lanza un reto a otro, se indican los ajustes de la partida (rival al que se reta, modalidad, número de tandas y tiempo) y el usuario retado decide si acepta el reto o no.

La parte del código que estoy desarrollando es la creación de la tabla con los retos que se van enviando los usuarios. La tabla la estoy creando con `TableModel` porque necesito añadir datos de forma dinámica, dado que el usuario puede enviar varios retos a distintos rivales si así lo desea (y por tanto la tabla tiene que actualizarse. Esta parte de la actualización la tengo preparada con un `JButton`).

Mi programa funciona con Sockets Java TCP Cliente-Servidor. Las clases que tiene mi programa son: Servidor, Cliente y Panel. Para la parte de la creación de la tabla me basta con usar mi clase Panel:

```
//Programa compilado con NetBeans IDE 8.2
//Versión de Java:
//java version "11.0.7" 2020-04-14 LTS
//Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.7+8-LTS)
//Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.7+8-LTS, mixed mode)

package practica.pkgfinal.mtpa;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Panel extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private JPanel panel = null;
    
    /*Varias declaraciones de componentes de Java Swing*/
    /* ... */
    
    private JTable miTabla = null;
    
    public Panel(){
        
        panel = new JPanel(){
            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                crearImagenes(g);
            }
        };
               
        panel.setLayout(null);

        /*Creación y configuración de varios componentes de Java Swing*/
        /* ... */
                
        TableModel miModelo = new ModeloTablaPersonalizada();
        miTabla = new JTable(miModelo);
        miTabla.setBounds(486, 110, 380, 120);
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(miTabla));
        
        this.add(panel);
 
    }
    
    /* Varios métodos. Setters y getters*/
    /* ... */
}

class ModeloTablaPersonalizada extends AbstractTableModel{

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() { //Número fijo
        return 4;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() { //Irá variando cuando añadamos retos (falta configurarlo)
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        int z = rowIndex + 1;
        int y = columnIndex + 2;
        
        return " " + z + " " + y;
    }
  
    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int c){ //Configuraré esto cuando arregle el error del JScrollPane
        return "Columna " + c;
    }
    
}
```

El problema que tengo es que no se muestra ni el `JTable` ni el `JScrollPane` si intento añadir lo segundo a lo primero. He probado a escribir `panel.add(miTabla);` en vez de `panel.add(new JScrollPane(miTabla));` y el resultado es que se muestra la tabla sin el encabezado y sin el `JScrollPane`. Si pongo los dos "add" anteriores no se me muestra nada.

¿Qué tengo que hacer para que me funcione el `JScrollPane` en mi `JTable`?

Edit: No me sirve como respuesta usar un segundo `JFrame` para ello. Sé hacerlo de este modo pero no es lo que se me pide en el enunciado. Debe estar todo en un único `JFrame` que es el que ya tengo.