# Cómo usar un ArrayList en un programa con sockets TCP Cliente-Servidor (java)

Tags: java, arraylist, socket, cliente

Esta pregunta se basa en el mismo programa que comentaba en la pregunta que he hecho hace 1-2 días ([Mi JScrollPane hace que mi JTable no se muestre (Java)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/381490/mi-jscrollpane-hace-que-mi-jtable-no-se-muestre-java)).

Estoy trabajando en un programa con Sockets TCP Cliente-Servidor. En la clase Cliente genero un ArrayList con los jugadores que se van conectando al programa.

Clase Cliente:

```
package practica.pkgfinal.mtpa;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Cliente{
    
    /*Declaraciones de variables*/
    /*...*/
    
    public Cliente(String aUsuarioInicioSesion){
        usuarioInicioSesion = aUsuarioInicioSesion;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String HOST = "127.0.0.1";
        final int serverPort = 9999;

        /*Declaraciones de variables String y Boolean*/
        /*...*/
        
        DataInputStream in;
        DataOutputStream out;
              
        try{
            Socket clientSocket = new Socket(HOST, serverPort);
            in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            
            int tipoPanel;
            Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            
            do{

                tipoPanel = miPanel.getTipoPanel();
                System.out.println("Tipo de panel: " + tipoPanel);
                
                switch(tipoPanel){
                /*En función del tipo de panel el contenido será uno u otro*/
                /*...*/
                }while(tipoPanel != 6);

            clientSocket.close();
            
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println(ioe.toString());
        }
    }

    private static ArrayList<Cliente> jugadoresConectados = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public static ArrayList<Cliente> devuelveJugadores(){
        return jugadoresConectados;
    }
    
    public static boolean marcarJugadoresOnline(Cliente cl){
        boolean estado = false;
        estado = jugadoresConectados.add(cl);
        return estado;
    }
    
    public static boolean marcarJugadoresOffline(Cliente cl){
        boolean estado = false;
        estado = jugadoresConectados.remove(cl);
        return estado;
    }
```

Clase Panel. Muestro uno de los métodos que es el `actionPerformed` de mis `JButton`, el cual incluye un botón para actualizar la lista llamado `actualizarLista`:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource() == aceptar){
            /**/           
        }else if(e.getSource() == salir){
            /**/
        }else if(e.getSource() == registrarseAqui){
            /**/
        }else if(e.getSource() == confirmarRegistro){
            /**/
        }else if(e.getSource() == atras){
            /**/
        }else if(e.getSource() == lanzarReto){       
            /**/
            
        }else if(e.getSource() == actualizarLista){
            
            setActualizarListaPulsado(true);
            int i;
            String jugador;
            listaUsuariosConectados.setText("");
            
            for(i=0; i<Cliente.devuelveJugadores().size(); i++){ //ERROR! Solo salgo yo. Recoger en ArrayList los inicios de sesión con éxito
                //Cliente cl = Cliente.devuelveJugadores().get(i);
                jugador = Cliente.devuelveJugadores().get(i).getUsuarioInicioSesion();
                listaUsuariosConectados.append("#" + jugador + "\n");
                System.out.println(jugador);
            }
            
            setActualizarListaPulsado(false);
        }
```

El `ArrayList` sí que me almacena mi nombre de usuario cuando inicio sesión en el sistema al ejecutar el Cliente una vez. El problema es que mi programa está pensado para que se almacene en dicho `ArrayList` los nombres de todos los clientes que inicien sesión de manera correcta, y no solo del primero que lo hace.

¿Qué puedo hacer para, al ejecutar varios clientes a la vez e iniciar sesión correctamente en ellos, se "comparta" el `ArrayList` de mis jugadores incluyendo a todos ellos?

Answer (score 0):

Eso suena a un catálogo de usuarios que han iniciado sesión en un controlador.

Hay, como casi siempre, muchas maneras de hacerlo. Pero básicamente se reducen a dos o tres posibilidades.

La primera es utilizar una variable global, es decir, un atributo de clase (estático) incluido en una clase principal, como la clase donde tienes el `main`. Esto, sin duda, es sencillo de implementar, no requiere de muchas líneas de código, pero provoca que todas tus clases dependan del lanzador de la aplicación. Por supuesto es muy fácil cometer errores al llevar esto a cabo, por lo que no es la opción recomendada, pero aquí te pongo un ejemplo de código.

```
public class Lanzador() {
    // Puede ser de tu Cliente, o de strings, según lo que quieras almacenar
    // Yo lo he escrito con una hipotética clase Usuario
    public static ArrayList<Usuario> usuariosConectados = new ArrayList<Usuario>();
    public static void main(string[] args) { ... }
}
```

Y en el punto donde se inicia sesión, solo añades usuarios a esta lista, incluso si lo haces en otra clase.

```
// Posible inicio de sesión
Usuario usuario = leerUsuario();
if (comprobarCredenciales(usuario))
    Lanzador.usuariosConectados.Add(usuario);
```

La segunda opción, más correcta, es meter este atributo de clase en un controlador, hacerlo privado, y que su modificación se haga a través de métodos que impidan que se pueda modificar la lista desde cualquier punto del programa.

Por supuesto, esta opción es algo más compleja, porque requiere que sepas sobre patrones de diseño, en especial el patrón modelo-vista-controladdor, o MVC.

En cualquier caso, lo que se haría es separar la aplicación en capas, donde el modelo son las clases o entidades en las que podemos conceptualizar el problema, como la clase `Cliente`,  por ejemplo. Entonces, todas las operaciones que pueda realizar un usuario, que interactúen con dicho modelo, se colocan el el controlador. Ejemplos serían métodos como `iniciarSesion`, `crearUsuario`, etc. Estos métodos hacen uso de las clases del modelo. Y la vista interactúa con el modelo a través del controlador, que es donde se encontraría la lista de usuarios activos que tú necesitas, pero esta vez como atributo de instancia (sin `static`) y privado. Lo único es que tienes que asegurarte de solo crear un controlador, no más instancias de la clase, cosa que puede hacer con el patrón *singleton*.

En cualquier caso, el controlador quedaría algo así:

```
public class Controlador {
    private ArrayList<Usuario> usuariosActivos = new ArrayList<Usuario>();

    public void iniciarSesion(string username, string password) {
        if (comprobarCredenciales(username, password)) {
            Usuario u = new Usuario(username, password);
            usuariosActivos.Add(u);
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: No consigo hacerlo la segunda forma. En cuanto a la primera, ¿tengo que crear la clase Lanzador aparte o usar una de mis existentes? Tanto mis clases Servidor como cliente tienen main y no sé como plantearlo ya que me parece exactamente igual que lo que ya tengo. Este es mi proyecto entero: https://shorturl.at/CGM78. El problema lo tengo en la línea 767 de la clase Panel al poner el número de jugadores en un ```JTextArea```. He hecho una serie de comprobaciones y no se actualiza correctamente y no sé que partes de mis métodos de ArrayList conservar. Tampoco sé mucho de Singleton y de MVC.